# SQL query. Difference between exists and join

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join, exists

I have 4 tables:

```
create table Product(pCode integer primary key, pName varchar(20), Color varchar(10);
create table Cli(cCode integer primary key, cName varchar(20), city varchar(20));
create table Sale(pOut integer references Product(tCode), cOut integer references Client(cCode), countOut integer, dtOut date, primary key (pOut, kOut);
create table Buy (pIn integer references Product(pCode), cIn integer references Client(cCode), countIn integer, dtIn date, primary key (pIn, kIn);
```

I need to display the names of clients are not from Kazan but those who buy some items in the first half of 2015, and then selling the same goods in the second half of 2015.

I solved this problem by using views.

```
create view vA as select cCode from Cli where Cli.City <> 'Kazan';
create view vB(cCode, pCode) as select cOut, pOut from Sale where '01.01.2015'<=dtOut AND dtOut<'01.07.2015';
create view vC(cCode, tCode) as select cIn, tIn where '01.07.2015<=dtIn AND dtIn < '01.01.2016';
create view vD as select * from vB inner join vC on vB.cKod=vC.cKod AND vc.pCode=vB.pCode;
create view vE as select * from vD  right outer join on vA on vA.cCode=vD.cCode;
create view vF as select distinct c.Knam from Cli as c inner join vE on vE.cCode=c.cCode;
```

Will it make a difference if I'm going to use instead join exists / not exists?

For example for vD - exists instead of inner join:

```
create view vD as select * from vB where exists(select * from vC where B.cCode=vC.cCode AND vc.pCode=vB.pCode);
```

For vE - not exists instead of right outer join:

```
create view vE as select * from vA where not exists(select * from vD where vA.cCode=vD.cCode);
```

Comment: Why would you create a bunch of views when you can readily do this in a single query?  Your code is hard to follow because the column names switch, which makes it much harder to give more concrete advice.

Comment: They are logically different. `SELECT * FROM a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT anything from any table)` can yield at most card(a) rows, while `SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON (some condition possibly involving a and b)` can result in at most card(a) * card(b) records, which might be larger than card(a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those questions that is best answered by using [`EXPLAIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-explain.html)

My guess is that you'll find that the optimizer chooses the same method between `INNER JOIN` and `WHERE EXISTS` (And conversely `Right Outer Join`/`Is Null` vs `Not Exists` since they are roughly equivalent in this scenario, and Postgres has a good optimizer.

[Here's a good example](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/16/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-postgresql/) of someone doing exactly the same test that you are doing for your `vE` query, and his results were that Postgres chose a `Hash Anti Join` for both methods.

Lastly, if you aren't sure which is the best route, just write both and see what works best. Check the stats after the query runs and look at `Explain`.

Answer (score 0):

I think exists is a better solution because common sense tell me it should be faster. If you say "exists" that means the query will stop when it finds the match but when you say "not exist" it needs to go through all the elements to be sure it doesn't exist.

Also I would like to encourage you to use better naming because the query is very hard to read right now.